# C++ Trying to read through file and write certain strings to other file

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream

`dictionary.txt` has the following words:

```
apple
orange
pear
kiwi
fruit
orange
plum
banana
```

in main:

```
cin >> userIn;
userIn = tolower(userIn);
stringCheck[loopCount] = userIn;

while (fileMain >> string1) {
  if (letterChecker(string1, stringCheck, loopCount) == 0){
    fileDupl << string1 << endl;
  }
}
```

in my function:

```
int letterChecker(char string1[], char stringCheck[], int loopCount)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i<loopCount; i++){
    if (strchr(string1, stringCheck[i]) == NULL){
      return 0;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Goal: I want a user to input a char. If a word from that txt file does not have an instance of the user input, I want the word to be written into a different text file (ex: user inputs 'a'. "kiwi", "fruit", and "plum" are written into the other txt file because they do not have an 'a').  I have figured out how to reset the error flags and location of the stream using the clear and seekg functions. The problem however, is when I run this code, the entire list gets written into the other txt file. It seems to completely ignore the function all together. Can you help guide me in the right direction?

Comment: The `letterChecker` might return 0 if the condition is true. What does it return otherwise?

Comment: It seems you end up with undefined behaviour as there are code paths reaching the end of `letterChecker()` without a `return` statement.

Comment: Did your compiler give any warning or error messages?

Comment: good point. Let me add a return. Should I get into the habit of always returning something?

Comment: Also, @Raedwald, the compiler gave no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a return statement of some int value at the end of the letter checker function.